# Conditionally override AntD Select styling in CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, conditional-statements

I have a form that contains an antD Select component.

```
          <Select
            name="SeasonId"
            onChange={onSeasonChange}
            placeholder="Choose Season"
          >
            // Select Options
          </Select>
```

[image]

I want to be able to change the colour of the border (and box shadow) depending on a condition. I am able to change/override the css I need by adding the following into a separate CSS file:

```
.ant-select-selector:hover {
  border-color: #1f9643e5 !important;
}

.ant-select-focused .ant-select-selector,
.ant-select-selector:focus,
.ant-select-selector:active,
.ant-select-open .ant-select-selector {
  border-color: #1f9643e5 !important;
  outline: 0 !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(49, 139, 54, 0.342) !important;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(49, 139, 54, 0.342) !important;
}
```

This changes the styling to what I am after:#

[image]

However, I only want to apply this style-override to the Select if a certain condition is met in code (i.e. I have an **isEditMode** state bool). I may be missing something obvious but interested on hearing any suggestions.

Comment: This question seems fairly opinionated for stack overflow, I think you're going to get downvoted

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what exactly you mean? How would you suggest I improve it?

Comment: You're asking for suggestions on improving code that you say already works, you mention applying the styles if a condition is met but don't further explain, and you have typos

Comment: "asking for suggestions on improving code that you say already works" - I thought that is exactly how Stack Overflow was meant to work...? Provide on example of where you have gotten to and ask for how to improve to meet my requirements? I admit I am not the greatest speller sometimes so would be grateful if you could advise where I have typos??

Comment: I was wrong you've been upvoted. Typo line 3 'separate'. From what I've heard so far from mods here is that asking for suggestions for your code is to be avoided, I understand your point and there is a fine line between suggestion and solution

Comment: To actually answer the question I would recommend looking into native HTML solutions for form inputs. You can use the disabled attribute on all of your form inputs when editmode is off for example, and style them based on that

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I have added a bit more detail and corrected the inevitable typo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a parent class name for your custom CSS code, and apply the class name to a parent element when the condition is `true`.

Example,
in your CSS file

```
.example.ant-select-selector:hover {
  border-color: #1f9643e5 !important;
}
```

and in your JSX file,

```
<div className = {`${conditon ? 'example' :''}`} >
   <Select />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this....! When I am back I will give it a go but seems to make sense! I will update once I have had a chance to try your suggestion.

Comment: I like this solution. One thing I would change: `className = {\`${isEditMode ? 'example' :''}\`}` to `disabled = {isEditMode ? "false" : "true"}`. Also @CJH try and avoid using !important by attempting to solve the specificity issue you are having

Comment: The className prop shouldn't be changed it is given for styling. If you want to disable the Select, so that the user cant interact, then you have to provide a `disabled` prop to the Select Component. btw it accepts Boolean values so you have to give true or false without the quotes.

Comment: I have implemented your suggestion but still no luck I'm afraid.  I will keep digging and update if I find a solution.

Comment: Had a bit of a poke around and tried a few things and got it working. It is essentially what you have put above however the wrapping DIV was not required... I was able to add the condition to the Select components className property. Also a bit of fiddling in the css as well. Thanks for this Rahuuzz!